# Which way should [speech] and [spoken-english] be merged?

Tags: discussion, retagging

There are two tags for the same concept, "English as spoken out loud": [speech](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech) (50 questions) and [spoken-english](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-english) (28). Neither has any followers.

Normally, of course, it's best to do the least amount of work and capitalize on the most common understanding by retagging questions into the one with the most. However, all but one of [spoken-english](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-english)'s questions were asked this year, and only 17 of [speech](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech)'s, so it seems that, given a choice, the newer tag is more popular. This is backed up by my intuition that it's a clearer tag.

Should we therefore reverse the usual retagging?

Answer (score 11):

I agree. I feel that [spoken-english](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-english) is significantly clearer than [speech](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech) and I would prefer that it be the "chosen" tag, regardless of the general tag popularity.